# Different Where Clause for each selected columns

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I originally had this query

```
SELECT
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '001' THEN value END) Col1,  
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '002' THEN value END) Col2,
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '003' THEN value END) Col3,  
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '004' THEN value END) Col4,
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '005' THEN value END) Col5,  
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '006' THEN value END) Col6

FROM table
WHERE id IN (001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006) and

DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) "2014-11-12"

AND

(value > -5 OR value > 5)


GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), MINUTE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) DIV 60
```

The reason for the `(value > -5 OR value > 5)` for the first case (Col1) I wanted it to only get the value that is > -5, and then same for the second case (Col2) I wanted it to only get the values that is >5.

Now I tried to use select on the where clause but it only outputted values on one column. So i thought Id change my query a little bit and so I changed it to something like this I have only done two columns first because I wanted to test it. But as soon as i hit Go its taking too long to execute.

```
SELECT ROUND(t1.floatvalue,3) C1, ROUND(t2.floatvalue,3) C2


FROM table AS t1

LEFT JOIN table AS t2

ON from_unixtime(t1.t_stamp/1000) = from_unixtime(t2.t_stamp/1000)

WHERE t1.tagid = "001" AND
t2.tagid = "002"

AND t1.floatvalue > -5 AND t2.floatvalue > 5

AND from_unixtime(t1.t_stamp/1000) BETWEEN "2014-11-14 09:00:00" AND "2014-11-14 11:00:00"

GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), MINUTE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) DIV 60
```

What is wrong with the second query that I did? I even specified the start and end time but still, its taking too long. (As I type its still loading)

Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN id = '001' AND value > -5 THEN value END) Col1,  
       MIN(CASE WHEN id = '002' AND value > 5 THEN value END) Col2,
       MIN(CASE WHEN id = '003' THEN value END) Col3,  
       MIN(CASE WHEN id = '004' THEN value END) Col4,
       MIN(CASE WHEN id = '005' THEN value END) Col5,  
       MIN(CASE WHEN id = '006' THEN value END) Col6
FROM table
WHERE id IN (001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006) and
      from_unixtime(t1.t_stamp/1000) BETWEEN '2014-11-14 09:00:00' AND '2014-11-14 11:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), 
         MINUTE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) DIV 60
```

BY the way, you can rephrase your `group by` as:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
```

And, you should use single quotes for date and string constants, rather than double quotes.  Double quotes work, but they are usually used for other purposes.